# How to convert text file characters to uppercase letters?

Tags: c

I am using C Programming Language. I want to convert characters in text file to uppercase letters and print text file contents on the screen after conversion.

Here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int main()
 {
 FILE *fptr;
 char filename[30];
 char ch;

printf("Enter filename you want to make capital letters: \n");
scanf("%s",filename);

fptr = fopen(filename,"r");

ch = fgetc(fptr);
while(ch != EOF)
{
ch = toupper(ch);
printf("%c",ch);
ch = fgetc(fptr);
}

fclose(fptr);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to convert text file characters to uppercase letters?

Comment: Code looks pretty good.. you call toupper, and display the result.  What exactly is the difficulty / problem??

Comment: It looks like the above code should do that - roughly.  Do you want to then re-save that info back to the file, or just print it?

Comment: Code isn't working, i want to print result at the screen. this is the problem

Comment: toupper function does not work.

Comment: @HamadaHosny:  I really think you should invest effort in being more clear.  Statements like, "Code isn't working" and "function does not work" are extremely vague.   When you say it isn't working, ask yourself exactly what is happening.  Did the program crash? Did it give incorrect output?  Did the program freeze? "Not working" can cover many, many scenarios, and when you aren't clear about what you are seeing, it is difficult for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are well on your way!  Here are some recommended adjustments:

First, `char ch` should be `int ch`.  Take a look at the manual page for `fgetch` and you will find that it returns an `int`.  This is actually pretty important, because the EOF returned will be out of range for a `char` but in range for an `int`.

Next, you could simplify a bit.  Why not:

```
while((ch = fgetc(ptr)) != EOF)
{
  printf("%c", (char)ch);
}
```

This moves your logical test and your read into a single line, eliminating the two lines that currently have the `fgetch` in them.

Finally, you should `#include<ctype.h>` since that is the header file where `int toupper(int)` is defined.

Comment: OP should also `#include <ctype.h>`.

Comment: Right you are.  I was thinking it was in string.h.

Comment: thanks you so much, that was helpful for me.

my welcomes to you from egypt.